# What is the name of the song playing at 01:15 of Magi, ep 25?

Tags: music, magi

Does anyone know name of the song that plays at 01:15 when Lady Scheherazade released the final Aberrant Magic granted to her (or, well, her clone version, anyway)?

I couldn't find a link; the only one I have is probably an illegal one anyway.

It is in episode 25 (final episode) of Magi - the Kingdom of Magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after going through a whole lot of songs in a [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLi1zu5BkZMhluoCsJLXkE9qf27C2ELEfw) on YouTube, I finally found it. The song is called "Warrior Ships" [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiGCxbGEcgk&list=PLi1zu5BkZMhluoCsJLXkE9qf27C2ELEfw&index=20).

Sadly, I could not find any information on the song that I could add to this answer such as who composed it or wrote it.

PS: I am not sure whether it is "20 Warrior Ships" or just "Warrior Ships". I had no idea, to be perfectly honest, but this is definitely it.

Comment: "Warriors Ship" is track 20 of the season 1 soundtrack: http://vgmdb.net/album/42806